# Improper Integral from minus infinity to $0$ of $xe^{2x}$

Tags: improper-integrals

Improper Integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 xe^{2x}dx
$$
I have got
$$
\lim_{t\to -\infty} [-1/4 - te^{2t} + e^{2t}/4]
$$
The answer in My book is $-1/4$ why?

Comment: What happens when you take the limit?

Comment: Let $t = -u$, then $u \to \infty$. Does that help?

Comment: @sidht yes,finally I got it thank you

Answer (score 3):

Because
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{4}-te^{2t}+\frac{e^{2t}}{4}\right)=-\frac{1}{4}$$
where
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}\left(te^{2t}+\frac{e^{2t}}{4}\right)=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(\frac{-u}{e^{2u}}+\frac{1}{4e^{2u}}\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-u}{e^{2u}}+\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{1}{4e^{2u}}=0$$
using L'Hopital for first limit 
$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-u}{e^{2u}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-1}{2e^{2u}}=0$$
for second is clear that it is $0$.

Comment: Nice to see you on, Adi. :-)